# Issues installing python sdk for couchbase on windows 10

Tags: python, visual-c++, couchbase

I need to install python sdk for couchbase on windows 10. 
I have installed VC++ build as well. I am using python 3.6 and couchbase 6.
I have used 'pip install couchbase' and 'easy_install couchbase' but in both the scenarios I am getting errored out.

pip install couchbase is showing "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-v3s8g3_0\couchbase\src\pycbc.h(193): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libcouchbase/couchbase.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2"

easy_install couchbase is throwing "fatal error LNK1158: cannot run 'rc.exe'"
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:152 (string):
  string sub-command REGEX, mode MATCHALL needs at least 5 arguments total to
  command.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:153 (string):
  string sub-command REGEX, mode REPLACE needs at least 6 arguments total to
  command.